# How to Install Ubuntu in windows 7 Partition?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7

I would like to try out the Ubuntu on my hard drive.

Now, I have C:/ as my windows 7 and D:/ as my media files and so on.

How can I best install Ubuntu to try out and uninstall it if I don't feel like it while it won't affect my files after I uninstall Ubuntu? I would like to dual boot with windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is run ubuntu via live-DVD

but, if you want to install it first, just follow these simple steps

from the dvd, run **wubi.exe**

[image]

And select the 2nd option ( in my language **"Install dalam windows"**/ or **"Install in windows"** ), and then

> 1. Select, which drive do you wan to install ubuntu
> 2. Select the size of installation ( it must be more than 8 GB )
> 3. Select Desktop Environment
> 4. Select language
> 5. Fill out the User name and Password and then click Install (or **"pasang"** in my language)

[image]

When you want to remove it, just boot up your windows -go to the drive (where the ubuntu installed) and go to "Ubuntu" folder and then Run **Uninstall-wubi.exe**

Answer (score 1):

If you are at first only wanting to check out Ubuntu i would rather suggest trying it LIVE instead of installing it..!!

You can do that with Ubuntu..!!

Make a *BOOTABLE CD/USB* with the *ISO* image youhave and just boot it..

This will be the 1st Screen you get-

[image]

In here,select the option <kbd>**TRY UBUNTU**</kbd> and you will enter the Ubuntu interface which you can  use as if you are using an actual installed operating system..!!

If you like it,you can install it either by *WUBI* or *as a separate partition* along with *Windows*

Answer (score 0):

Go to www.ubuntu.com, click on download, then click on the link that says:

```
Looking for an easy way to install on Windows? Check out the Windows installer
```

Couldn't be easier.